# Wireless IP Camera

Tags: video, wireless

At present I have a software solution that involves 4 analogue cameras connected to an encoder that is plugged into my router. My application then reads the rtsp feed from the ip address from this connection.

The problem I have is that it seems difficult to get installers for my product for various reasons (based here in UK).  If I used wireless digital cameras then it would not need qualified electricians to install these analogue cameras.

But, all the products I have seen for all this is that the wireless cameras uses it's own software to deal with rtsp feeds. I cannot seem to get access to the feed (I am using VLC).

Are there any wireless cameras on the market that I could look in using?

Additional
My C# Desktop app is looking for an rtsp feed from my video encoder that is just a black box that decodes analogue signal and encodes it to a digital output.  I am trying to create a product that will be easy to install but as the industry stands in the UK getting installers to install 4 analogue cameras is difficult. If I can remove the need for installers then that is a great step forward for me.

Comment: What is the actual use case?  This is pretty borderline, but I think there may be enough of a possible use case for it to be useful.  If it was just doing slow refresh cameras, then it wouldn't be, but the ability to use wireless IP cameras for video production would require similar things, so it seems useful enough.

Comment: @AJHenderson Hi, Thanks for your comment.  I shall edit my question.

Answer (score 1):

Don't have any experience with Wifi Security Cameras but this one here would fit your specs, aswell as the other IP cameras from that company:
http://foscam.us/wireless-ip-cameras/foscam-fi9805w-wireless-ip-camera.html

I have not used their cameras and can't tell you if they are any good.

Actually a lot IP enabled security cameras fit the specs. As long as they have a web interface they offer a stream usable by VLC, you just have to visit their web interface and get the url for the stream. VLC understands more than just RTSP, RTMP f.e. is much more used for web streaming nowadays.

Comment: The cameras are so-so.  I got one for use as a baby monitor.  It works ok, but the mic and speaker on it are nearly worthless (might be a defective model, but others with the model I got have similar issues.)